# How to fix spans wrapping in a button

Tags: html, css

I have a `button` with `span` tags inside. The `span`s appear to take up the full width of the `button`, and every `span` is on a new line. How can I fix this so that the `span`s are all part of the same line?

What I want

[image: What I want]

What I get

[image: What I get]

Code (attributes not shown):

```html
<button>
    <span>[</span>
    <span>1/8</span>
    <span>1/8</span>
    <span>]</span>
    <span>[</span>
    <span>1/4</span>
    <span>]</span>
    <span>[</span>
    <span>1/8</span>
    <span>1/8</span>
    <span>]</span>
    <span>[</span>
    <span>1/4</span>
    <span>]</span>
</button>
```

Comment: To know what is wrong in your code, it helps to see it. Can you post your code, please?

Comment: This is primary steps not answer. Before you review your code try to view it on browser like Firefox and use inspect elements then change span width or button width then if it still gambling. Copy your HTML code + CSS code and post them here .

Comment: @Creative87 I have already attempted to edit widths with same issue. _(I know this is late)_

Comment: If it's don't work as expected so I suggest use class like <button class="classbt"> then in CSS use  .calssbt{width =20px;} that should work give it try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: flex;`
You can study more about `display: flex` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Note: Add the style to the container element